# Dual Lorentz spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, interpolation-spaces

MO seems the perfect place to ask for the following question. Denote the Lorentz spaces on an arbitrary measure space $(E,\mu)$ by $L^{p,q}=L^{p,q}(E,\mu)$, and by $p'$ the conjugate index of $p$.

QUESTION: If $1<p,q<\infty$, is it true that $(L^{p,q})'\simeq L^{p',q'}$ with equivalence of norms?

This result is easily available in the literature under the assumption that the measure space is $\sigma$-finite and non atomic, so my question concerns the validity of the statement on *arbitrary* measure spaces.

The reason I believe this to be true is that Lorentz spaces can be characterized as real interpolation spaces $L^{p,q}\simeq(L^a,L^b)_{\theta,q}$ for suitable $a,b,\theta$, up to equivalent norms. Then the general property $(A_0,A_1)_{\theta,q}'\simeq (A'_0,A_1')_{\theta,q'}$ can be applied, which holds under a minimal density assumptions of $A_0\cap A_1$ in both $A_j$. Since $(L^p)'=L^{p'}$ does not require anything on the measure, provided $1<p<\infty$, the result should be true also for Lorentz spaces.

Am I missing something?

Comment: A brief check: Triebel also assumes a $\sigma$-finite measure space to establish the Lorentz space interpolation, whereas Bergh-Löfström seem not to require it (or they hide it well).

Comment: Note that the result is certainly true for $p=q$, and it is difficult to think that something might go wrong when $p\neq q$